# error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object

Tags: github, commit, gnupg

Well, I have removed all my gpg secret keys from Linux mint cz they were making problems while committing on Github.
even after deleting those I still get these errors. please help
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `gpg.program` config to the `gpg` path helped me.
To find out `gpg` path run:

> $ which gpg

In my case the git-bash tells it is in path `/usr/bin/gpg` so I ran:

> $ git config --global gpg.program /usr/bin/gpg